# Haskell: Graham Hutton Book-(old-Yellow), Parsing (Ch-8)

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I copied this example exactly as it appeared in the book (first version).

given in the book:

```
p :: Parser (Char,Char)

p =  do x <- item
        item
        y <- item
        return (x,y)
```

compile error on x, Why?

|

```
40 | p =  do x <- item
   |         ^^^^^^^^^

:40:9: error:
    * Couldn't match type `([(Char, String)], [(Char, String)])'
                     with `[((Char, Char), String)]'
      Expected type: Parser (Char, Char)
        Actual type: String -> ([(Char, String)], [(Char, String)])
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- item
      In the expression:
        do x <- item
           item
           y <- item
           return (x, y)
      In an equation for `p':
          p = do x <- item
                 item
                 y <- item
                 ....
(deferred type error)
```

Comment: Could you write down the type of `item` please?

Comment: item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
                   [] -> []
                   (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Parser is just an alias of a function, so it makes use of the Monad instance of (->). That's why you get `String -> ([(Char, String)], [(Char, String)])` instead of `Parser (Char, Char)` or `String -> [((Char, Char), String)]`.

I would recommend to create a new type yourself and instantiate Functor, Applicative and Monad to get the expected results.

This would do the work:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \case
  [] -> []
  (c:cs) -> [(c, cs)]

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f p = Parser $ \s ->
    concatMap (\(a, s) -> [(f a, s)]) $ parse p s

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = Parser $ \s -> [(a, s)]
  pf <*> pa = Parser $ \s ->
    concatMap
      (\(f, s') -> fmap (\(a, s'') -> (f a, s'')) (parse pa s'))
      (parse pf s)

instance Monad Parser where
  return a = Parser $ \s -> [(a, s)]
  pa >>= f = Parser $ \s ->
    concatMap (\(a, s') -> parse (f a) s') (parse pa s)

p :: Parser (Char,Char)
p =  do x <- item
        item
        y <- item
        return (x,y)
```

Comment: Stephen Diehl's tutorial is also a great resource http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html

Comment: I suppose you’re using `concatMap` to be consistent but you can use plain old regular `map` or `fmap` in your `Functor` instance and your instance for `<$>` seems a tiny bit convoluted, why not `concatMap (\(f, s') -> fmap f pa s') (parse pf s)`? If you were feeling particularly silly I guess `parse pf s >>= uncurry (flip fmap pa)` but that is obtuse

Comment: Totally. You can write it as clever as you want it to be. I just find the way I wrote it easy to understand for beginners.

The Functor instance would look more terse like:
`instance Functor Parser where
   fmap f p = Parser $ fmap (first f) . parse p`
The Applicative instance:
`instance Applicative Parser where
  pf <*> pa = Parser $ parse pf >=> (\(f, s') -> first f <$> parse pa s')`
Monad:
`instance Monad Parser where
  pa >>= f = Parser $ parse pa >=> (\(a, s') -> parse (f a) s')`
But, again, I think it doesn't help here

Answer (score 0):

You have `type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]`?

Therefore you are using the `(->) String` `Monad` instance. So `x` has type `[(Char, String)]`, as does `y`. Your code wants to `return` the pair `(x,y)` which has type `([(Char,String)],[(Char,String)])`. Therefore you get `p :: String -> ([(Char,String)],[(Char,String)])` but you are claiming that `p :: Parser (Char, Char)` which is the same as `p :: String -> [(Char, Char)]`. These don’t match so you get a type error.

Your problem is that you are treating `Parser` like a monad but it isn’t. Specifically you expect:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
return :: a -> Parser a
```

But you have:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> ([(a,String)] -> Parser b) -> Parser b
return :: [(a,String)] -> Parser a
```

Or more generally:

```
(>>=) :: (String -> a) -> (a -> String -> b) -> (String -> b)
return :: a -> (String -> a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't defined the monad instance for type `Parser`. You can try to do so or just use the [library for parsing](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/Parsing.lhs) that includes the definitions from the book.